# How to capture http requests headers and body

Tags: http, tcpdump, wireshark

I need to capture all incoming/outcoming http traffic of a unix machine, and then run a script on each http header/body.

I have found that **tcpdump** captures all the requests, but big ones end up being split into multiple frames and is not easy to patch them together with a script that uses **libpcap**.

**tcpflow** almost does what I need, but it puts the whole flow between the host/client in the same file, without a good token to separate them making it impossible to know when a request ended and other started automatically.

**Wireshark** has the "follow http" option, but I couldn't find a way to use **tshark** to export one file for each flow.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Isn't this the job of the web server? Or of a proxy?

Comment: use [tcpick](http://tcpick.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: It's probably easier to force it through a transparent proxy using iptables instead of trying to reassemble all captured traffic.